# JavaFX - Netbeans9 - JDK11 : can't run

Tags: java, netbeans

I have installed JDK11, Netbeans9 and JavaFX. I have followed the tutorial here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx
(javaFX and netbeans -> non modular IDE)

The code recognizes the javafx modules. But when I run the project i get the attached error: 
[JavaFX deployment library not found in active JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX8MA.png)

Extra screenshot with the settings:
[Project-Properties-Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSNvI.png)

Comment: Within the solution properties did you define where your SDK is installed?  The information provided does not make this clear.

Comment: @Ramhound I have added a screenshot of the properties. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: It’s complaining about the JDK not the JavaFX